# Passing required arguments into instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, pvlib

While the substance of this question is specific inside the `pvlib` library, I believe the error is general in nature and other questions may help with answer.

I am using a function named `total_irrad` from the `pvlib` library (documentation here: http://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pvlib/irradiance.html#total_irrad).

When I call the function and pass it the correct arguments, I get the error: `TypeError: total_irrad() takes at least 7 arguments (11 given)`. I understand that I have supplied all 11 available arguments, and that this `TypeError` is telling me that of the 11 arguments, 7 are required and I have not passed in the correct required items.

I suppose first and foremost, is this understanding correct (from here: [Error: function() takes at least n arguments (n given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473468/error-function-takes-at-least-n-arguments-n-given)).  If correct, how can one know which are the required items and which are not.  Or, if I am wide off the mark, can anyone offer any suggestions.

```
total_irrad = pvlib.irradiance.total_irrad(
    surface_tilt=20, 
    surface_azimuth=solpos['azimuth'], 
    solar_zenith=solpos['zenith'], 
    solar_azimuth=solpos['azimuth'], 
    dni= clearsky['dni'], 
    ghi=clearsky['ghi'], 
    dhi=clearsky['dhi'], 
    dni_extra=dni_extra, 
    airmass=airmass, 
    albedo=0.25, 
    surface_type='grass',
    model='haydavies', 
    model_perez='allsitescomposite1990')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any required arguments, do not have a `={Default}` following them.  You are missing the required arguments:

```
apparent_zenith
azimuth
```

Comment: was just about to type that.